# Differences between 细腻, 细致, 精细 and 深入

Tags: vocabulary, difference

All 4 words listed above all in some way have the meaning of fine, exquisite, detailed. So what are the differences between them? Please provice some examples

Answer (score 2):

「细」 in 「细腻」，「细致」 and 「精细」 denotes 'detailed'

> 「腻」 has the meaning of 'saturated/ rich', 「**细腻** mainly means '**exquisite**'
>
> Example: 「小说中对感情的描写十分**细腻**」 - In the novel, the depictions of emotions are very **exquisite** (rich in details)

~

> 「致」 has the meaning of 'neat',  「**细致**」 mainly means 'neat and **detailed**'
>
> Example: 「小说中对感情的描写十分**细致**」- In the novel, the depictions of emotions are very **exquisite** (neatly displayed in details)

~

> 「精」 in 「精细」 has the meaning of 'refined' 「**精细**」 mainly means '**precise**'
>
> Example: 「小说中对感情的描写十分**精细**」- In the novel, the depictions of emotions are very  **precise** (accurately detailed)

~

> 深入 literally means 'in-depth'
>
> Example: 「小说中对感情的描写十分**深入**」 - In the novel, the depictions of emotions are very  **in-depth** (thorough and detailed)

Other Examples:

「细腻刻画」 - exquisite (*rich and detailed*) description

「细致图案」 - detailed (*detailed and neat*) patterns

「精细安排」 - precise (*refine and detailed*) arrangement

「深入调查」 - in-depth (*thorough and detailed*) investigation